# Как вставлять html в php get_header()

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Не могу понять как мне вставлять HTML код из другого файла в index.php чтобы сформировать полноценную страницу. Например

```
HTML название header.php

<div class="test"> bla bla bla </div>

HTML index.php
...
<?php get_header() ?>
...
```

Надеюсь смысл понятен.

Comment: фу, вордпрессы пошли)

Answer (score -2):

Откройте/создайте файл header.php в шаблоне вашей темы и туда вставьте ваш html. Если файл не будет найден в шаблоне темы, то он будет браться отсюда:
wp-includes/theme-compat/header.php.

документация:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_header

p.s Вообше не рекомендую тратить свои силы и время на изучение ворпресса, лучше изучите нормальный фреймворк типо laravel, раз уж выбрали php.

Comment: Я думал это можно делать без wordpress, я хотел бы написать свой код(сайт) но использованием разделения, как в wordpress типо шапка, подвал, запись и т.д

Comment: @Edvard это можно делать и без WordPress, все верно. Если на чистом PHP, то используйте [include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php), [require](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php).